# MySQL database is not updating according to the query

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

```py
@app.route('/subscription-update-details', methods=['POST'])
def subscription_update_details():
    try:
        result = [{'msg': 'success'}, {'msg_code': '200'}]
        if request.method == 'POST':
            subscription_update_details = request.get_json()
            subscription_id = subscription_update_details['subscriptionId']
            subscription_type = subscription_update_details['subscriptionType']

            connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=HOST_NAME, user=USER_NAME, password=PASSWORD,database=DATABASE)
            mycursor = connection.cursor()

            query1 = "UPDATE subscription SET subscription_type=%s WHERE subscription_id=%s"
            val1 = (subscription_type,subscription_id)



            mycursor.execute(query1, val1)

            connection.commit()
            return jsonify({"result":"updated"})
```

Comment: What's your question about this code?

Comment: this is not updating the data in database

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all relevant information, for example about your debugging attempts